# Blender bevel not working correctly

Tags: modeling, bevel

I was trying to bevel some edges for an extruded wall, but the bevel goes weird and doesn't do it the way is should, I think it's because of the length difference, but on past projects, it didn't happen.

[image]
[image]

Comment: before the bevel, apply the scale in Object mode (Ctrl A)

Comment: I already scaled the object to a reasonable size @moonboots

Comment: Do you _mean_ to  have a vertex halfway down the edge closest to us? Include edges both sides of it in your selection?

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Iv'e sent the file to blend-exchange with the question URL. https://blend-exchange.com/b/bJVWSyKR

Answer (score 0):

As @moonboots suggested, you need to apply your scale. Lots of Blenders tools are dependent on the objects scale and can give strange results if the scale is X=1 Y=1 Z=1, including the bevel tool.

Press `ctrl-a` and choose Scale in Object mode, then try your bevel operation again.
Once you apply the scale you should see in the Sidebar (what we call the N-panel) your objects scale change to 1,1,1
[image]